# How do I use an individual checkbox value from a wordpress meta box?

Tags: wordpress, loops, checkbox, meta

I'm trying to use a metabox checkbox to hide/display on hover. The problem is it shows the div if any of the posts have the check box checked. I need it to toggle the div "on" & "off" depending on if the checkbox is checked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code in my functions.php:
    `// Checkbox Meta
    add_action("admin_init", "checkbox_init");

```
function checkbox_init(){
add_meta_box("checkbox", "Check to Show Bubbles", "checkbox", "homefeature", "normal",    "high");
}

function checkbox(){
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$field_id = $custom["field_id"][0];

echo '<label>Show Bubbles?</label>';
$field_id_value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'field_id', true);
if($field_id_value == "yes") {
$field_id_checked = 'checked="checked"';
}
echo ' <input type="checkbox" name="field_id" value="yes" '.$field_id_checked.' />';
}

// Save Meta Details
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');

function save_details(){
 global $post;

  if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
   return $post->ID;
}

update_post_meta($post->ID, "field_id", $_POST["field_id"]);
}

function custom_content($id) {
$field_id = get_post_meta($id, 'field_id', true);

if($field_id == yes) {
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
         echo '$("this").mouseover(function() {';
     echo "$('#mainFeatureFlashBG').css({'display' : 'block'})";
     echo '}</script>'; 
}
else{
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
       echo '$("this").mouseover(function() {';
   echo "$('#mainFeatureFlashBG').css({'display' : 'none'})";
   echo '}</script>';
}
}`
```

Here is my php:

```
        <ul>  
            <!-- Begin Miller Beer Logo Query-->                      
            <?php
            $args=array(
              'beerlogo'=>'miller',
              'post_type' => 'homefeature',
              'post_status' => 'publish',                
              'posts_per_page' => -1
            );
            $my_query = null; 
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args); 
            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

              while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                 <li class="image-rollover"><a href="<?php echo     esc_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'homefeature_custom_link', true));
            ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>               
            <?php
        //Is the Checkbox for Bubbles Checked?
        custom_content(get_the_ID());               
    ?>             

             </a>
            </li> 

                <?php
              endwhile;
            } 
            wp_reset_query(); 
            ?>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check with:

```
<?php

if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'field_id',true) != '') {
 // do something, output div
} ?>
```

See function reference here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: That didn't work. It echoed out the jquery to hide/show the div, but didn't actually execute the jquery